# Deleting multiple items from the IndexDB

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I’m currently working with an IndexDB and I need to delete a list of objects from it.
I have a mathod that deletes one object, which works very well.
The important part of this method is this snippet:

```
openDatabasePromise.then(function (db) {
      var tx = db.transaction(objectStoreModel.name,     dbModel.accessTypes.readwrite);
      tx.onabort = function () {
        $log.error("Error deleting object in local indexeddb: ", tx.error);
        deferred.reject();
      };

      var objectStore = tx.objectStore(objectStoreModel.name);
      var deleteRequest = objectStore.delete(objectId);
      deleteRequest.onsuccess = function () {
        deferred.resolve();
      };
      deleteRequest.onerror = function (errorMessage) {
        $log.error("Error deleting object in local indexeddb: ", deleteRequest.error);
        deferred.reject();
      };
}
```

However, executing this function in a loop results in no object being deleted, but no error being shown.

Is this a known error for someone?
Could the error be, that I try to dispatch a lot of promises at once?

Comment: Why not pass an array of values to be deleted to this function, instead of calling it once per loop cycle?

Comment: Because my knowledge of using the localstorage are a step before being basic :) The code i posted is not mine, it's just code, I'm calling.
I suspected the mistake being in there, but I will try to add a similar method deleting an array, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tip fixed the problem, but mostly, because it forced me to implement the code snipped anew.
This help me to find the actual error which was, that `objectStore.delete(objectId)` expects `objectId` to be a number, but it was a String in my case.

Thanks a lot!